# Taking a screenshot from a panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to take a screenshot from a panel which i draw some horizontal lines over it.
 [image: Panel Drawn]

I used this code:

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    //hide close button
    pictureBox1.Visible = false;

    //Take screenshoot for the DPanel.
    Bitmap dend = new Bitmap(dPanel.Width, dPanel.Height);
    Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(dend);
    System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle = dPanel.RectangleToScreen(dPanel.ClientRectangle);
    G.CopyFromScreen(rectangle.Location, System.Drawing.Point.Empty, dPanel.Size);
    SomeGlobalVariables.Mygraph = dend;

    Reporttoprint r = new Reporttoprint();
    r.Show();
}
```

There is an exception happened when i clicked on linkLabel1.

[image: Exception]

it seems that when i click on linkLabel1 to execute the code and take a shoot from my Panel, dPanel_Paint action is called again then the exception is fired !

Exception in this region:

```
private void dPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (k==0)
    {
        //add the "Group" center point to the dictionary.
        ClusterPoint=new Point(((ep1.X+ep2.X)/2),((ep1.Y+ep2.Y)/2));
        //Exception is done here
        clusterpoints.Add(Clusterchar[k], ClusterPoint);
    }
}
```

any help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: On which row is the exception thrown?

Comment: so find where you are intesrting twice and if whatever it is that you are inserting is already there use that to know that you are recursing

Comment: To save graphics drawn on the Panel in its Paint event use panel.DrawToBitmap!

Comment: The Paint() event, when subscribed, is raised every time a control needs to repaint itself (maybe, when `Reporttoprint` is shown on top of your Panel). Some conditions don't change, and you end up adding the same key to the Dictionary twice. Also, you could take TaW advice and use `.DrawToBitmap` to draw your Panel's surface to a Bitmap (and Dispose the objects you create in the process).

Comment: Paint event is for drawing. Looks like __you don't do any drawing__ in the Paint event..?!?!?! - The exception is obvious; never add to a Dictionary without Key checking! But: What are you doing there anyway??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the paint event fires very, very often (depending).

Problem is you have duplicate keys.  Two solutions.

Overwrite existing key/value pair:

```
clusterpoints[Clusterchar[k]] = ClusterPoint;
```

Or don't add at all if key already exists:

```
var key = Clusterchar[k];
if(!clusterpoints.ContainsKey(key))
    clusterpoints.Add(key, ClusterPoint);
```

Comment: Thanks, it woks ^^